# Como puedo abrir una clase Activity desde un menu Fragment

Tags: android-studio, android-fragment

Tengo creado un menú horizontal desde el que voy abriendo diferentes Clases que extienden de Fragment, pero necesito abrir una clase que extiende de AppCompatActivity

Utilizo este código **MainActivity.java**

**Opción 1**

```
private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Menu1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Menu2();
                break;
            case 2:
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu3.class); 
              startActivity(intent);
            case 3:
                fragment = new Menu4();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = null;
        }

        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}

}
```

**Opción 2**

```
private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return new Menu1();
            case 1:
                return new Menu2();
            case 2:
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu3.class); 
              startActivity(intent);
            case 3:
                return new Menu4();
            default:
                return new Menu1();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}

}
```

Si pulso en la opción para abrir el Menu3, se abre bien la clase AppCompatActivity, el problema es que, si pulso primero en el menú para abrir el Menu2, se abre el Menu3, en el Logcat no muestra ningún error.

Agradecería vuestra ayuda para intentar solucionarlo.

Un saludo.

Answer (score 1):

Eso es porque no has puesto un break después de la opción 2.

```
private class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment;
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                fragment = new Menu1();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new Menu2();
                break;
            case 2:
              fragment = new Menu2();
              Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Menu3.class); 
              startActivity(intent);
              break;
            case 3:
                fragment = new Menu2();
                break;
            default:
                fragment = null;
        }

        return fragment;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 4;
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Hola @solamente, si que lo puse, pero lo quite porque el  `return fragment;` me arroja un error **Variable fragment might not have been initialized** y si cambio **Fragment fragment;** por **Fragment fragment = new Fragment();** funciona igual, y si lo cambio por **Fragment fragment = null;** se produce un error y se cierra la aplicación

Comment: Modifico mi respuesta, he añadido un fragment por defecto para evitar el error que te esta dando ya que al abrirse un nuevo activity el fragment que haya no debería importar, si importara deberías mirar primero cual esta seleccionado en ese momento.

Comment: Sigue pasando lo mismo, si pulso la opción Menu2() primero se muestra la pantalla del Menu3()

Comment: Puedes explicar el caso mas concreto segun entiendo si la opcion position = 2 se te abre el activity Menu3.class es eso?

Comment: si, así es, no se porque pulsando el menú 2 me muestra primero el menú 3, cuando tengo a la vista la pantalla del menú 3 que es una pantalla para introducir una contraseña, si pulso el botón atrás se quita y ya muestra la pantalla del menú 2

Comment: eso es lógico ya que le estamos diciendo que cambie el fragment = new Menu2(); y abre el nuevo activity encima por esa razón en cuanto se cierra o se hace back se muestra el Menu2()

Comment: Pero si quitamos del la opcion posicion = 2 el codigo que se ha pueto **fragment = new Menu2();** pasa lo mismo, muestra primero la posicion = 3

Comment: No acabo de ver el problema si tienes el proyecto subido a github o alguna otra plataforma para poder compartirlo y hacerme una idea mas clara del problema.

Comment: He cambiado la opción del menú en el primero post, aunque el comportamiento es el mismo, subi en una ocasión un proyecto para que un compañero lo probase, y no se ahora mismo como esta ese proyecto, voy a ver si puedo verlo, si no creo uno nuevo y lo vuelvo a poner en github, tardare un rato a ver si me acuerdo como subirlo porque en esa ocasión me costo lo suyo, dime si te da igual que lo suba por ejemplo al servidor de MEGA lo subiría antes, si no intento en github

Comment: Github es mejor pero como veas mega no sería un problema. En tu ejemplo de la opción 2 que has añadido sigues sin poner un break justo después de llamar al nuevo activity.

Comment: Mira esta aqui a ver si puedes entrar github.com/SoCu/Prueba.git los menus no tienen el mismo nombre que he puesto aqui, el break del segundo ejemplo no lo he puesto, porque si lo pongo me da error. dime si puedes ver el proyecto en github porque es la primera vez que lo utilice en esa ocasión

Comment: Lo puedo revisar sin problemas, cuando encuentre el error te aviso

Comment: Quieres que cada vez que le des al boton de VerEsta se habra la nueva activity y ahora mismo unicamente lo hace la primera vez es correcto?

Comment: Aquí te dejo una versión de como sería. https://github.com/sssolammm/Prueba

Comment: No, cuando pulse el menu VerEsta se tendria que abrir el Esta2() y cuando pulse en el menu Alarmas se tiene que abrir Alarmas_Login.class, que se abre pero mal, porque tapa los menus, estoy probando con el codigo que tengo, y al poner la contraseña veo que en ese proyecto la aplicacion se cierra.

Comment: Ya lo he modificado, en todo caso lo que tienes es un problema de conceptos no de código. Una de 2 o creas un fragment que tenga la pantalla de contraseña y lo pones el switch case o abres una nueva activity como se esta haciendo hasta ahora. Pero si en esa activity quieres que se mantengan los menus tienes que replicarlos ahi obligatoriamente.

Comment: De momento voy a intentar solucionar el problema del menú, luego veré lo de replicar los menús en el activity porque no es la única activity que tengo con ese problema, el poner el código para que pida la contraseña en un Fragment lo intente pero no lo conseguí hacer, por eso probé desde la clase Activity, pero tengo ese problema que salta el menu Alarmas cuando pulso en VerEsta, he vuelto a cargar el codigo que dices que has vuelto a modificar pero sigo viendo el anterior en el que en case 3 se llama a Esta2()

Comment: Revisalo de nuevo lo he subido. A mi no me realiza ningún tipo de salto si la información que aparece es confusa ajustarla en el switch case pero no debería hacer salto alguno.

Comment: No se si estamos viendo lo mismo, ahora veo que has cambiado la opción y llamas a Alarmas() que es un Fragment, y ahí no pide la contraseña, el menu Alarmas tiene que llamar a Alarmas_Login, si va a ser un problema, voy a intentar hacer que pida la contraseña desde un Fragment, sabes de algun codigo que sirva de ejemplo, porque como te he comentado ya lo intente y no conseguir hacerlo desde un Fragment